# Any HTTP library in C that allows direct communication with the server?

Tags: c, http, ssl, libcurl

Do you know of any HTTP client library in C (with SSL support) that also allows direct communication with the remote server?

I have a client-server application where the client uses HTTP to start a session in the server and then tells the server to switch the connection from HTTP to a different protocol. All communication is encapsulated in SSL. It is written in Perl and works well, but I'm looking into implementing the client in C.

I know libcurl gives you access to the underlaying socket but it's not enough because of the SSL requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that libcurl doesn't do the SSL part by itself, it uses OpenSSL. So, if you can get the socket handle from libcurl after the first HTTP interactions, AND the session key it uses (some spelunking required) you can go on directly with OpenSSL from that point.

Comment: It seems the function you need is Curl_ssl_getsessionid, which is not documented. So my answer is an option only if you don't have restrictions about using undocumented interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I don't see how I could use Curl_ssl_getsessionid, but reading the curl source code I see that the CURL session is actually a pointer to a "struct SessionHandle" which stores a cache of connections. So in theory I should be able to use something like this to write directly to the SSL channel:
`CURL *curl = ...;
struct SessionHandle *handle = (struct SessionHandle *)curl;
struct connectdata *conn = handle->state.connc[0];
SSL *ssl = conn->ssl[0].handle;`

Comment: I would rather say you should look at CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY and then curl_easy_recv / curl_easy_send. No need to poke at source or go outside of the API.

Comment: Thanks, but if you use CONNECT_ONLY you have to create the request and parse the HTTP response yourself, something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must be looking for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) otherwise you must have to write it yourself, like [this](http://www.koders.com/c/fid71B0BF647B74045F0948415B7C62AC3020AA09BF.aspx)

Comment: I would also recommend this simple HTTP documentation: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [Web Sockets](http://websocket.org/). Don't know if there's a C library available though. I would assume there is, if you dig.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't had a look at websockets before. What I'm trying to achieve is very similar. It looks like these guys have a C library for them: http://warmcat.com/